# Delete similar Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, filter, duplicates

**drop Duplicates from Data which are similar based on measurement inaccuracy**

I'm struggling with a new Problem in Python for filtering of Data Duplicates.
I am especially searching for a possibility to use it on big Data with more than 100 rows and over 25 columns.

Reducing to an easy example with the following Dataframe:

```
>>> df
   a         b         c         d
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
1  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
2 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
3  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
4 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
5  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
6  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
7  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163
8  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
9  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303

>>> df1 = df.drop_duplicates()

   a         b         c         d
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
2 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
3  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
4 -0.103219  0.410600  0.144044  1.454274
5  1.240291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
7  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163
8  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303



>>> df2 = df. spezial code ?

   a         b         c         d
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
2 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
3  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
5  1.240291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
7  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163
8  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
```

So the `drop.duplicates()` in `pandas` is very efficient and super fast and works very well.
But it only filters duplicate which are totally the same. 
But to minimize Date with look on measurement inaccuracy I would also like to drop Data which is similar and based on defined measurement inaccuracy the same.

So should also drop Row 4 which is 'almost' the same than Row 2 in column `c`.

On the other hand, it should stay Row 8 which is similar to Row 5 (in column a) but not in the measurement inaccuracy.

following a posibility what solve the the question for smal data but unfortunatly it is way to slow to work on big Data.

```
tolerances = {'a':0.001,
              'b':0.5,
              'c':0.5,
              'd':0.05}


df_clean = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns.to_list())
df_clean = df_clean.append(df.iloc[1])

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df_clean.shape[0]):
        m = 0
        for key in tolerances:
            if ((df.iloc[i].loc[key] <= df_clean.iloc[j].loc[key]+tolerances[key]) and (df.iloc[i].loc[key] >= df_clean.iloc[j].loc[key]-tolerances[key])):
                m = m+1
            else:
                break
        if m == len(tolerances):
            break
    if j == (df_clean.shape[0]-1):
        df_clean = df_clean.append(df.iloc[i])


df_clean.sort_index(inplace=True)

>>> print(df_clean)
           a         b         c         d
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
1 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
2  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
4  1.240291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
5  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163
6  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
```

Comment: You mean you would like to remove rows that are _similar enough_? For that, you would need to know what distance (_similar_) to use, and what threshold (_enough_). Natural examples of distances are Euclidean distance, or cosine similarity. And in your case, it seems like a high threshold of > 95% would do the job.

Comment: Thats right. The distance depends of the rows so some value should be filtered in acuracy of 0.1 and for other should be around 0.01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your input data:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': {0: '1.764052', 1: '-0.103219', 2: '0.761038', 3: '-0.103219', 4: '1.240291', 5: '1.532779', 6: '1.230291'}, 'b': {0: '0.400157', 1: '0.410599', 2: '0.121675', 3: '0.410600', 4: '1.202380', 5: '1.469359', 6: '1.202380'}, 'c': {0: '0.978738', 1: '0.144044', 2: '0.443863', 3: '0.144044', 4: '-0.387327', 5: '0.154947', 6: '-0.387327'}, 'd': {0: '2.240893', 1: '1.454274', 2: '0.333674', 3: '1.454274', 4: '-0.302303', 5: '0.378163', 6: '-0.302303'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
tolerances = {'a': 0.001, 'b': 0.5, 'c': 0.5, 'd': 0.05}
tolerances_values = np.fromiter(tolerances.values(), dtype=float)

>>> print(df)
           a         b          c          d
0   1.764052  0.400157   0.978738   2.240893
1  -0.103219  0.410599   0.144044   1.454274
2   0.761038  0.121675   0.443863   0.333674
3  -0.103219  0.410600   0.144044   1.454274
4   1.240291  1.202380  -0.387327  -0.302303
5   1.532779  1.469359   0.154947   0.378163
6   1.230291  1.202380  -0.387327  -0.302303
```

You want to remove rows that are similar enough based on a distance you provide: differences between rows must not be larger than values defined in `tolerances`.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

# Define your similarity function between rows. 
def is_similar(x, y):
    """
    Returns True if x is similar to y, False else
    """
    diffs = np.abs(y-x)  #  Look at absolute differences
    similar = all(diffs <= tolerances_values)  # True if all columns diffs are within tolerances
    return bool(similar)

# Compute similarities on all your dataframe
similarity_values = pdist(df.to_numpy(), is_similar)

# Convert np.array() into a pd.DataFrame()
similarity_df = pd.DataFrame(squareform(similarity_values), index=df.index, columns= df.index)

# Get indices of similar rows
similar_indices = similarity_df[similarity_df == True].stack().index.tolist() 

# Remove symmetric indices (from i,j i,i and j,i only keep i,j)
similar_indices = [sorted(tpl) for tpl in similar_indices if tpl[0] < tpl[1]]  

# Flatten 
similar_indices = list(set([item for tpl in similar_indices for item in tpl]))
```

Now here you go:

```
>>> df[~df.index.isin(similar_indices)]
          a         b         c         d
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
2  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
4  1.240291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
5  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163
6  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303
```

---

**[Outdated] Other example using a cosine_similarity distance**

Define a function to compute similarities and retrieve indices where similarity is higher than a threshold:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity  # any other can be used

def remove_similar(df, distance, threshold):
    distance_df = cosine_similarity(df)
    similar_indices = [(x,y) for (x,y) in np.argwhere(distance_df>threshold) if x != y]
    similar_indices = list(set([item for tpl in similar_indices for item in tpl]))
    return df[~df.index.isin(similar_indices)]
```

Now you can try with `distance=cosine_similarity` and play with thresholds:

```
>>> remove_similar(df, cosine_similarity, 0.9)

          a         b         c         d
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
2  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
5  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163

>>> remove_similar(df, cosine_similarity, 0.9999999)

          a         b          c          d
0  1.764052  0.400157   0.978738   2.240893
2  0.761038  0.121675   0.443863   0.333674
4  1.240291  1.202380  -0.387327  -0.302303
5  1.532779  1.469359   0.154947   0.378163
6  1.230291  1.202380  -0.387327  -0.302303
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good but actually not solved my Problem or i did´t got it..

Comment: At the time of my answer, you didn't provide the similarity logic you needed. In fact, my answer still applies but what you need is an other distance, namely a simple absolute difference e.g. for inputs x and y, result is |x-y|. And what I called thresholds is what you call tolerances.

Comment: That´s correct, thats why i added it, to clear the problem up.
Do you have an idea for a fast solution?

Comment: Edited my answer to work with your update. Hope that's fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works very well! Don't know why the results variate a bit from the other solution. Looks like, that this one filter out some more Values. But that should be no Problem. More important is, that it works much faster than the other solution! For a Test-Set with around 1000 Datapoints your Solution is with only 3 Secounds 300% faster!

Comment: looks like it works up to arround 10.000 points but for much more it isn´t efficiently neither.

Comment: By "other solution" do you mean the one you implemented? Or the alternative I suggested usine `cosine_similarity`? If it is the latter, then the performance is different because the computations are different and expected results are different - probably a cosine() is more expensive than a simple diff as you need. You could use a profiler to see what part is actually the bottleneck :)

Comment: with ''other_solution" i meanted the slow one, which i implemented. The first alternative with cosine_similarity i didn´t got it to work similar as the other two solutions.